# Is there a way to apply sum to product identities for multiples of cosinus

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any unitary way to turn from sum to product expressions such as :
$$\cos(3x)+2\cos(2x)+\cos(x)$$
$$\cos x+\sqrt{2}\cos(3x)+\cos(5x)$$?

Comment: What do you mean by “unitary?”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Some sort of formula or more generally way to solve all problems of this kind( in this case turning a sum of more than 2 cosine where some are multiplied by some integer) to a product.

Comment: Try expanding functions of nx to functions of x.

Comment: $\cos(nx) ~:~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ can always be converted into a polynomial in $\cos(x)$.  For example, $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1$ and $\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3(x) - 3\cos(x)$.

Comment: $\cos(5x) = 16\cos^5(x) - 20\cos^3(x) + 5\cos(x).$

Comment: My **blind instinct** is that since you **must** end up with a polynomial in $\cos(x)$ it should be possible to *construct* the necessary coefficients such that when the polynomial is of degree $\geq 5$, the polynomial has no real roots in $\cos(x)$.  That is as far as my thinking takes me.

Comment: Using the identity $\cos x = \frac{1}{2} (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$, you can substitute $\cos kx$ for any value of $k$ which allows you to write all equations like this as powers of $e$. Not all of these are solvable, as there are certain polynomials of degree $5$ or above whose roots cannot be expressed in a closed form (Abel-Ruffini theorem).